# Symfony2 Edit Without Form Builder

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, doctrine

I want to edit(update) some field in database from form without using form builder in symfony 2.4, for example i have id, username, password, first_name,last_name, ...., added, updated,
in this case i just want to update, first_name, last_name and updated field.

could you give some idea how to update only some field in symfony.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: are u using doctrine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your user details by `find()` method by using doctrine entity manager

```
    $id = /* user id that you want to edit/update*/
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userEntity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Users')->find($id);
```

Then use setter methods for updating values

```
    $userEntity->setFirstName('new first name');
    $userEntity->setLastName('new last name');
    $userEntity->setUpdates('updated name or date');
    $em->persist($userEntity);
    $em->flush();
```

this will update you user data